# Call existing trigger on Opportunity Update

Tags: triggers, visualforce

Probably an easy answer I cannot find. I'm trying to call an existing trigger when the Opportunity Stage is set to 'Closed Won'. Not sure how to execute it. The existing trigger executes a Visualforce component.

```
trigger create_cc_project on Opportunity (after insert,after update)
 {
    if(Opportunity.stagename=='Closed Won')
 then(cc.ccUtility.asyncInitiateProject('Opportunity', Opportunity.Id));
    }
```